# Javascript code to add class to svg class not showing in html

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a code snippet that adds fill color to svg when you hover and removes it when you leave. But the code is not coming up. I have the code before the closing body tag.Here is my code;

```
<script>
     (function(){

        var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('path');

        Array.from(svg).forEach(function(item) {
            item.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
                    item.setAttribute('style','fill:green;');
            });
            item.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
                    item.removeAttribute('style','fill:green;');
            });
        });

        })();
</script>
```

It does not change the fill color but when i add it to console it works fine. I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/gbtqLdc6/). It's not how I would do it (I'd use a class or just [a CSS `:hover` rule](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/09835ds2/1/)), and separately you don't want to pass that second argument to `removeAttribute`, but it does *work*.

Comment: Does it throw an error in the console, or just not work? You might need a leading semicolon `;(function(){...`. If there's any script immediately before it from another block that doesn't terminate in a semicolon, it won't work the way you expect it to.

Comment: @jmcgriz it does not throw an error. I even added an alert inside the function and it runs just fine.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder alright i would take a look at your own method though.

Comment: @PatrickObafemi - I don't know what you mean...?

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but those `path` elements definitely exist when your script runs, right? If it works from the console but not embedded, it sounds like maybe they're being added asynchronously or something

Comment: @jmcgriz That was my first thought, but he says that an alert works, so the listener is being added to the elements.

Comment: I really appreciate the help. so i created a minimalistic version of the app here https://jsfiddle.net/n7xa95mz/3/ and i noticed it works fine. When i copy the full svg file inside a div it works okay but calling it via an object tag does not work at all. Am at loss as to why that is tbh